# powershell add a sequence number between 01 and 15 per file and remember last number added

Tags: powershell-3.0

I have an interesting problem with PowerShell, I cant think of how to solve it so far..

We need to add a sequence number to a file and it has to be between 01 and 15 and it must increment.

Additional to that the number needs to be remembered.  So for example we get a file during the day, the script runs, add the sequence and stops.  First one is going to be

foo_01_bar.txt

Second one that might arrive would trigger the script again and this time would be named to..

foo_02_bar.txt

All the way until we get to

foo_15_bar.txt

and then the number is reset.

I tried creating a text file to store the value so that when the script stops and then runs again it will remember it.  But I just cant see how to get that stored value to match the value to be incremented then added to the filename..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly that should be what you want:

```
#Generate sequence with leading zero for numbers < 10
$sequence = 01..15 | % { if($_ -lt 10){ "0$_" } else { "$_" }  }
$sequencePointerFile = "sequence_pointer.txt"
$sequencePointer = -1;

# Read pointer from file
if(Test-Path $sequencePointerFile) {
   $sequencePointer = [int] (gc $sequencePointerFile)
   if($sequencePointer -eq ($sequence.Count -1)) {
        #Reset
        $sequencePointer = -1
   }
}

$sequencePointer++

# create file with specific number - Use force to overwrite files if 
# sequence starts again from 01..
new-item "foo_$($sequence[$sequencePointer])_bar.txt" -Force

# save pointer
$sequencePointer | Out-File $sequencePointerFile
```

Comment: Thank you so much that is exactly what I needed.  I best hang up my powershell hat now :)